# How does the University of Bristol's AI fixed-wing perched landing change the wings?

Tags: landing, fixed-wing, artificial-intelligence

The BBC radio program Click's [2017-01-24 episode](http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/player/p04pr3cf?t=380), starting at about 06:20, describes the use of AI to develop a perched landing capability by an autonomous fixed-wing craft. I can't understand exactly what is happening.

While the BBC's Gareth Mitchel suggests the winds "sweep up", BMT Defence Service's Antony Waldock says that they move or rotate forward, and goes on to say, *roughly transcribed*:

> ...as you are about to stall you rapidly pitch-up the aircraft, and that pitch-up gives you a little bit of extra lift, and that stops you (from) kind-of mushing into the ground, so you can 'pick it up', and land with minimal velocity at a particular location.

BBC's Bill Thompson then describes the technique as a change the wing shape allowing a controlled stall to lose velocity really quickly and manage the descent.

I'd like to understand if the wings "sweep up" or do they move forward, and is this movement considered a change in the wing's shape? Or are they otherwise changing shape?

Comment: [Maybe this news article helps](http://newatlas.com/drone-perch-uav-landing-bristol-university/47349/) or [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU0WDWV6au8&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: @RonBeyer [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lsfo9uN8Cik) attempts to explain in detail (though still ends with a stall and fall). Would you be interested in summarizing as an answer? This isn't my area of expertise; I'm not likely to get it right if I try to answer myself. Thanks!